# Can not access folder which has created by Java application in my PHP application

Tags: java, php

I have a normal web application which are store user details and their images, we are creating user wise run time folders to store their all profile pictures.
example:- `upload/user_1/anyimage.jpg`

Also I have another java process(running as thread in server) which we are using to parse user data in bulk and after parsing we save it in database also we are creating run time folder to store user's profile pictures with same file structure.
example:- `upload/user_2/anyimage.jpg`

Now problem is:- when user 2 wanted to change their profile picture using UI(php application) using `move_upload_file()`
we are getting permission denied error.

When I have investigate more deeply I found that when folder has created using java application its owner is root and my php application is running under daemon user so that's the reason behind permission denied error.

How to overcome this problem, because we neither can change user who is running php application(because its system backend user) nor my java application.

As I am very new to this forum, please let me know if this is write place for this.

Comment: Needs to update folder permissions.Give full access i.e. 777

Answer (score 0):

use chmod

```
chmod('/path/to/folder/, 0755);
```

if you want to change the ownership use:

```
$path = "/path/to/folder" ;
$user_name = "root";

// Set the user
chown($path, $user_name);
```

Comment: thanks @Guns, but this will not solved my problem, its not permission issue, its ownership issue. Also what about folder created by java applications? permission are same for both(created by Java or Php) but owners are different. hope you understand now.

Comment: again wrong! let me explain by example, suppose folder1 is created by java program and its owner is root and now my php application(which is running under deamon user) is trying to access that folder, now you got it? plz let me know if need more clarification here.

Comment: Great! then you might want to edit the java program and have the permission specified while the folder is created

Comment: Can't! because 'daemon' is system user its not any specific user like root or any other it can be change run time.

Comment: did you try chmod with 777 permission via terminal or php?